# Scaling SVG until a max value

Tags: html, css, svg

i'm sorry but i just really can't get this to work and none of the solutions i've found appear to work for me.

I'm drawing a svg star/pentagram and i want it to be centered and scaling until it fills about 40% of the page height.

Since it is a square image, right now when the window size increases it just scales to enormous sizes and fills like 2-3 window heights. The usual max-width, max-height dont seem to work for svg, putting it into a container wasnt optimal either. With way too much css i got it to stay smaller but then the content below would just wrap around and be displayed next to it instead of underneath.
In short, it just won't work as i want it to and i have no clue how i can fix that.

```
        <svg class="simon-svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn0" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M50 275 L300 275 L250 425 Z" fill="red" stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn1" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M400 50 L300 275 L500 275 Z" fill="green"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn2" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M500 275 L750 275 L550 425 Z" fill="blue"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn3" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M650 700 L400 530 L550 425 Z" fill="orange"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn4" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M175 700 L400 530 L250 425 Z" fill="turquoise"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
```

Comment: You can do this in CSS: `svg{width:40vh; display:block; margin:0 auto}`. If you need it centered in the middle of the page : `svg {
  width: 40vh;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question completely, but it seems to work just fine for me:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg class="simon-svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn0" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M50 275 L300 275 L250 425 Z" fill="red" stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn1" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M400 50 L300 275 L500 275 Z" fill="green"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn2" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M500 275 L750 275 L550 425 Z" fill="blue"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn3" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M650 700 L400 530 L550 425 Z" fill="orange"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g class="svg_button" class="clickable" id="sbtn4" cursor="pointer" pointer-events="all">
            <g class="svg-background">
              <path d="M175 700 L400 530 L250 425 Z" fill="turquoise"stroke="black"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      
      lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

Comment: oh man now i feel dumb, why didn't i just fix the height from the start haha. i think it was because on unrealistic window sizes (large height, very small width) the image is too broad for the screen. In the real world i'm sure this wont be an issue so i will go with your solution, thanks! In case i'm running into an issue with that i'll just decrease the vh a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I not sure what exactly you want, but I try to anwser some of them that I got.

**SVG** element is some kind of like **img** that both of them are **inline-block** by default, so **inline** elements will linear align with them happily.

So if you try to make **SVG** behaved like the **div** you can make it block by:

```css
svg {
    display: block;
}
```

The alternative way is that you can wrap that **SVG** into a block element, such as:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg class="simon-svg" viewbox="0 0 800 800">
       .... ...
    </svg>
</div>
```

*div.wrapper*'s height will proportional grow or decrease with that SVG because you give it a *viewbox* attribute.

Hope my answer makes points to you.